# How to access element from jArray with Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, json.net

I want to get the first or default element of jArray into an object

```
{[
  {
    "timex": "XXXX-08-25",
    "type": "date",
    "value": "2016-08-25"
  },
  {
    "timex": "XXXX-08-25",
    "type": "date",
    "value": "2017-08-25"
  }
]}
```

(This array can be different by the next call) How can I get the value of "value" from the first element in an object with linq? This: "2016-08-25"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your json seems not valid, because it's starts with "{[". On valid JSON input you can use this code:

```
var input = "[ {  \"timex\": \"XXXX-08-25\",\r\n    \"type\": \"date\",\r\n    \"va2lue\": \"2016-08-25\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"timex\": \"XXXX-08-25\",\r\n    \"type\": \"date\",\r\n    \"value\": \"2017-08-25\"\r\n  }\r\n]";
var jArray = JArray.Parse(input);
var result = jArray.FirstOrDefault()?["value"]?.Value<DateTime>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this i think this is answer what you want!

```
var myData = {[
  {
    "timex": "XXXX-08-25",
    "type": "date",
    "value": "2016-08-25"
  },
  {
    "timex": "XXXX-08-25",
    "type": "date",
    "value": "2017-08-25"
  }
]}

List<MyDataList> _myDataList = new List<MyDataList>();

foreach(var item in myData)
{
    MyDataList _myDataListObject = new MyDataList();

    Dictionary<string, object> desirializedJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(item.ToString());

    myDataListObject.timex = Convert.ToString(desirializedJsonObject["timex"]);
    myDataListObject.type= Convert.ToString(desirializedJsonObject["type"]);
    myDataListObject.value = Convert.ToString(desirializedJsonObject["value"]);

    myDataList.Add(myDataListObject);
}

//Get first records data
MyDataList _myData = myDataList.FirstOrDefault();

//Your class to get data
public class MyDataList
{
    public string timex {get; set;}
    public string type {get; set;}
    public string value {get; set;}
}
```